# Mark item as 'selected' in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am currently having a slight problem with trying to get an item "selected".

Before selection, the HTML code looks as follows:

```
<div class="class cpm-text-header2" title="Header 2" styleclass="header2">Header 2</div>
```

What I am trying to do is upon click, change the above code to the following:

```
<div class="class cpm-text-header2 selected" title="Header 2" styleclass="header2">Header 2</div>
```

I have tried the following code, where by I I try to use the 'replace' function so I can manually inject the word "selected" into it however this does not work.

Is there an alternate way to do this?

Current code is as follows:

```
var whatHeaderIsSelected = ($('#textStyleButton').text());
//whatHeaderIsSelected returns text "Header2"
var finder = $('#classSelector').children();
for (i = 0; i < finder.length; i++) {
    var whatsSelectedInToolContainer = ($(finder[i]).text());
    if(whatHeaderIsSelected==whatsSelectedInToolContainer) {
        var getHTML = ($(finder[i]).prop('outerHTML'));     
        whatHeaderIsSelected = whatHeaderIsSelected.toString().toLowerCase();
        whatHeaderIsSelected = whatHeaderIsSelected.replace(/\s/g, ""); 
        var getDivNameOfHeader = "class cpm-text-"+whatHeaderIsSelected;
        getHTML.replace(getDivNameOfHeader, getDivNameOfHeader+" selected");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)?

Comment: have a look into jQuery `toggleClass` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work fine

```
$(".cpm-text-header2").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this out, instead!

**jQuery**:

```
$(".cpm-text-header2").click(function(){ // on click
    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); // toggle "selected" class to the clicked element
});
```

and some **CSS**, so you know the `class` has been toggled:

```
.cpm-text-header2.selected{
    background: red;
}
```